# Building WebRTC using ninja and debugging in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, webrtc, ninja

I am trying to build and debug the latest version of WebRTC in VS2013. Building inside from VS2013 fails, although using ninja directly (e.g., ninja -C out\Debug) works fine.  Ideally I would like to edit, start a build and debug in VS2013:

> If you do a system install of VS2013, you can use it for editing and
>   debugging. ninja will still use the depot_tools version to build. This
>   is preferred as it's automatically kept up-to-date as build
>   requirements change.

I have followed the steps described here:

```
http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/build-instructions-windows#TOC-Setting-up-the-environment-for-Visual-Studio-2013
```

I have this environment variable set:

```
GYP_GENERATORS=msvs-ninja,ninja
```

I have run the following command:

```
C:\dev\webrtc>gclient runhooks
```

(At the end of the command, I get a few "**Warning: unrecognized tool MASM while converting to MSBuild.**" warnings)

**Update**: These warnings disappear if I remove the GYP_GENERATORS setting and run "gclient runhooks" again.

I then open "C:\dev\webrtc\trunk\all.sln" in VS2013 and try rebuilding the "peerconnection_client" project.  But it fails with the following errors:

```
Error   1   error : loading 'build.ninja': No such file or directory    C:\dev\webrtc\trunk\talk\ninja
Error   2   error MSB3073: The command "call ninja.exe -C trunk\out\Debug\ -t clean peerconnection_client" exited with code 1.  C:\dev\webrtc\trunk\talk\peerconnection_client.vcxproj  308
```

"C:\dev\webrtc\trunk\talk\ninja" folder does not exist but my "build.ninja" file is in each of my C:\dev\webrtc\trunk\out(Debug | Debug_x64 | Release | Release_x64).

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: how did u solve the problem error: call ninja.exe exited wth code 0?

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone has this error, you need to install DirectX SDK